# Adding new item into object (Angular, Ionic2)

Tags: jquery, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I guess it's a simple JavaScript question, but still... I can't figure it out, I tried everything (I guess not)...

I'm trying to add multiple items into the `this.cart` which is stored in Ionic Storage (like LocalStorage).

When I add 2 items to the cart:

```
updateCart(id, qty) {
    this.storage.get('cart').then((result) => {
        if(result) {
            this.cart = result;
        }
        else {
            this.cart = [];
        }

        this.cart.push({
            id: id,
            qty: qty
        });
    });

    this.storage.set('cart', this.cart);

    this.storage.get('cart').then((result) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    });
}
```

It returns:

```
[{"id":"48131","qty":1}]
```

Instead of:

```
[{"id":"48130","qty":1},{"id":"48131","qty":1}...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move it inside the callback,

```
 this.storage.get('cart').then((result) => {
        this.cart = result;
        this.cart.push({
        id: id,
        qty: qty
        });
    });
```

Comment: which means  this.storage is empty

Answer (score 0):

```
updateCart(id, qty) {
    this.cart = [];

    this.storage.get('cart').then((result) => {
        this.cart.push(result);
    });

    this.cart.push({
        id: id,
        qty: qty
    });

    this.storage.set('cart', this.cart);

    this.storage.get('cart').then((result) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    });
}
```